# Fill text in modal from URL (bootstrap)

Tags: html

I need help to fill text in modal like this site, here the example:

When I add text in URL -> ?tamu=stackoverflow

https://kristyaputri.digital-bali.com/?tamu=stackoverflow

The modal will show with stackoverflow text.

For other example, the text in URL is bootstrap4

https://kristyaputri.digital-bali.com/?tamu=bootstrap4

The modal will show with bootstrap4 text.

How to make site like this? I see the view source/source code but not get any clue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[This website](https://kristyaputri.digital-bali.com/?tamu=stackoverflow) uses server-side script to display text from URL parameter value

you can use a simple PHP code like this

```php
<p class="paragraph-modal"><b>Kepada</b> <br /> <?php echo $_GET['tamu']; ?></p>
```

or using javascript

```js
<p class="paragraph-modal"><b>Kepada</b> <br /> </p>
<script>
document.querySelector("p.paragraph-modal").insertAdjacentText("beforeend", new URL(window.location.href).searchParams.get("tamu"));
</script>
```

Comment: Why I can't see the script/JS in that site? Is it hidden?

Comment: @boiboi the answerer mentions that it's a server-side script, meaning that it won't be visible to you